# Alteration of digits - Smallest number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What's the smallest natural number that starts with $15$ that becomes $5$ times when these digits are moved to the end?

Obviously the original number must end in $3$ (so that $\times \,  5 = 15$). Also its third digit must be $7$ or $8$, since the third digit becomes the first digit of the altered number.

So if the intermediate part has a length of $n$ digits, the number must be of the form: $15XX\ldots X3$ where $XX\ldots X$ has $n$ digits.

Any ideas on how to continue?

Comment: Do you mean with first two digits 1 and 5?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ManishKundu yes!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thank you, I will try to understand the MathJax techniques by going through the documents. Sorry, I am 58 y.o. and not very familiar with technology :(

Comment: $157894736842105263\cdot5=789473684210526315$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let all the $m$ digits after "15" form the number $y$. Prepending the "15" means $15\cdot10^m+y$, while appending "15" means $100y+15$, so we have the equation
$$5\,(15\cdot10^m+y)=100y+15,$$ i.e.
$$y=\frac{15\cdot10^m-3}{19}.$$ 
Now we can solve this with a bit of modular arithmetic, or like this:
$1/19=0.05263\color{red}{157894736842105263}1578947368421053\ldots$

Comment: Professor Vector you are brilliant!